# How to get params sent by JQuery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to send parameters by $().load.

I tried this, to send:

```js
$('#result').load('form.html', {'doc_id': '12'});
```

On form.html i try to read the doc_id via this function:

```js
function getUrlVars() {
    alert ('Drin in getURL');
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    alert ('Hashes:' + hashes);
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

But this doesn't work.
I think the reason is that the URL does not change when using the JQuery.load() function. The function getUrlVars is trying to read out doc_ic from URL but since the URL does not change, it fails.
So how do i get doc_ic in form.html?

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this form `{'doc_id': '12'}` makes POST request. You can try these variants:

1) `$('#result').load('form.html', 'doc_id=12');`

2) `$('#result').load('form.html?doc_id=12');`